# On VSCode, when 'running code", why does VSCode reference anaconda library files even though I selected venv?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

Refer screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYjEg.png
(I am new here and cannot post images yet)

So the steps I took were the following:

1. Create venv and run venv
2. Install my libraries
3. Choose the same interpreter when I was running my script
4. Select ['Run Code']   (albeit there was an error but ignore that)
5. Had the error.

Code:
ImportError: ..... (C:\Users....\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\text_spliter.py)

May I know why it references anaconda3 instead of my venv file path?

When I ran 'Python File', I realised it references the correct venv folder.

Comment: Please post the code and error as a text, ant an screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You must have the *CodeRunner* extension installed. You use `Python: Select Interpreter` to select the interpreter for vscode, or to be precise, for **Python** extension. Because this is the functionality brought by the **Python** extension. *CodeRunner* will only use the python environment in the system environment variable by default. Your choice of **Python** extension will naturally not affect the *CodeRunner* extension.

`Run Code` will use *CodeRunner* to execute the script.

`Run Python File` will use the **Python** extension to execute the script.

***Whether to use the python version displayed in the lower right corner of the interface***

| Extension | Command |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [CodeRunner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) | Run Code | NO |
| [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) | Run Python File | YES |